# Similar function to to_scipy_sparse_matrix in Julia sparse matrices functions

Tags: python, julia, sparse-matrix

I would like to ask if there is equivalent function in **Julia** language and its [functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/arrays/?highlight=sparse#sparse-matrices) for sparse matrices to [to_scipy_sparse_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html#networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix) in **networkx**.

I am looking for equivalent to calling this function in [eigenvector centrality algorithm](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/centrality/eigenvector.py#L206).

Is there possibility to run this function as stated above, in eigenvector centrality link, in **Julia** to produce the same output ?

Thanks for any suggestions. I am struggling few hours with this and I am unable to make any results.

**Edit:**

```
Python version :
import networkx as nx
import scipy

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, w=1.0 )
G.add_edge(1, 3, w=0.5 )
G.add_edge(2, 3, w=2.5 )

M = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, nodelist=list(G), weight='w',dtype=float)

print(M)

Output:
(0, 1)  1.0
(0, 2)  0.5
(1, 0)  1.0
(1, 2)  2.5
(2, 0)  0.5
(2, 1)  2.5

Julia version:
using Graphs

g1 = Graphs.graph(Graphs.ExVertex[], Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex}[],     is_directed=false)
d = "dist"

v1 = add_vertex!(g1, "a")
v2 = add_vertex!(g1, "b")
v3 = add_vertex!(g1, "c")

e12 = add_edge!(g1, v1, v2)
e12.attributes[d]=1.0

e13 = add_edge!(g1, v1, v3)
e13.attributes[d]=0.5

e23 = add_edge!(g1, v2, v3)
e23.attributes[d]=2.5
```

Comment: if `g` is the graph, it is possible to get a sparse adjacency matrix naively as `A = sparse(adjacency_matrix(g))` (using `Graphs.jl`)

Comment: But what if graph is weighted? Function in networkx returns one matrix and some kind of vector i think that is connected or is representing weight.

Comment: It would be easiest if you include Julia code to build a sample graph to which you want to generate a sparse matrix (you can edit the Question). These manipulation are usually nifty one-liners.

Comment: I added Julia and Python version. I would like to replicate pythons **to_scipy_sparse_matrix** in Julia.

Comment: `sparse(weight_matrix(g1,map(x->x.attributes[d],edges(g1))))` generates a sparse matrix (but goes through a dense representation first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (following OP Julia code):

```
julia> triple(e,d) = (e.source.index,e.target.index,e.attributes[d])
triple (generic function with 1 method)

julia> M = sparse(map(collect,zip([triple(e,d) for e in edges(g1)]...))...,length(g1.vertices),length(g1.vertices))
    2x3 sparse matrix with 3 Float64 entries:
    [1, 2]  =  1.0
    [1, 3]  =  0.5
    [2, 3]  =  2.5
```

`triple` returns a (source,target,d-attribute) triple which might come-in useful in other places as well.

The sparse matrix is created with the `sparse(I,J,D,rows,cols)` constructor where `I,J,D` are all same length vectors and for each index `i` for them, the matrix had a `D[i]` value at position `I[i],J[i]`.

If a symmetric weight matrix is needed, use the following:

```
julia> M = M+M'
3x3 sparse matrix with 6 Float64 entries:
    [2, 1]  =  1.0
    [3, 1]  =  0.5
    [1, 2]  =  1.0
    [3, 2]  =  2.5
    [1, 3]  =  0.5
    [2, 3]  =  2.5
```

Comment: Could you please provide again your last coment for making sparse matrix without going through dense representation first? I would like to like at it more deeply. I will approach in this answer but I do not think that it will give me correct results. Next will be calculating eigenvalues and eigenvector from this matrix so I will need output as it is stated in Python. I am not sure why M matrix in python code have such values for same graph as constructed in Julia.

Comment: That comment is the same as the answer here (only without separating `triple` into a separate function). The output here and in python is the same, the only difference is in the print formatting of sparse matrices, and that the python matrix is symmetric (hence 6 values instead of 3). Symmetricizing a matrix is as simple as `M = M + M'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Python must be indexing vertices in that matrix from 0 and Julia from 1 or is my assumption wrong ? I would like to know what represent those pairs of numbers.